# Check UDT Table For Nullability In Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

```
type NumberTable is table of number index by binary_integer;

create procedure TestNumberTable
(
    p_NumTable         IN NumberTable Default Cast(Null as NumberTable)
)
as
    /* code body */
```

Two questions:

1. How to check the parameter for nullability inside the stored procedure?
2. How to find count(*) [i.e. row count] of parameter inside the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a UDT with "index by binary integer", you can do this:

```
create type NumberTable is table of number;
```

Q1: by "nullability", do you mean "whether it is null"?  If so this will work:

```
create procedure TestNumberTable
( p_NumTable IN NumberTable Default null)
as 
  if p_NumTable is null then
     ...
```

Q2: for count:

```
create procedure TestNumberTable
( p_NumTable IN NumberTable Default null)
as 
  dbms_output.put_line ('count is '||p_NumTable.count);
  ...
```